# Why this WPF window is not sizing to its content having SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"?

Tags: .net, wpf, resize, sizetocontent

I've created this simple demo because I'm having some trouble making auto-sizing work in WPF. This is the simple code:

```
<Window x:Class="UnderstandSizing.Window3"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
ResizeMode="NoResize" >

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TabControl Grid.Row="0" >
        <TabItem Header="CCCC" />
    </TabControl>        
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Text" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

As the grid has everything set to Auto and the window is configured to sizetocontent I expected to have the TabControl and the button and nothing else at the window but there are empty spaces on it. Look:

[image: Design time] Design-time

[image: Runtime] Run-time

I must be missing something ...

Comment: You listed what your WPF sample is doing, but I'm not clear on what behavior you are expecting. Can you let us know what you are expecting, so we can point you in the right direction? NVM I see the detail in the question...

Comment: I suspect it is just holding room for the actual TabItem.  Put a TextBox in the TabItem.  Right now you only have a Header.

Comment: As for width I suspect the border title area is using that much space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears the the window has a minimum width that you can't go below even if you turn resize on. This might have to do with the buttons at the top. If you set `WindowStyle` to `ToolWindow` it will appear as the correct size. Interestingly if you set it to `None` it will initially be the same size as the default, but you can resize it smaller.

Anyway, do you really want your window to be this small? If your width is bigger, the window will correctly snugly fit the control.

Comment: It's just a test because I'm having problems with the real window. Let me try again with bigger sizes.

Comment: Ok, you were right, but I still have the problem so I will create a new question and accept this question in 3 minutes (SO rules ... :\)